# Setar OPTION como SELECTED com base em valores do banco de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-select

Estou a preparar um formulário onde estou a setar os valores do campos com os dados do banco de dados.

Estou com dificuldade em setar a opção escolhida como `selected` para o `<select/>` no código em baixo:

**PHP**

```
<!-- ATENCAO -->
<label>Tipo Beneficiario: </label> <span> <? echo $TipoBeneficiario; ?> </span>
<div class="">
  <select name="tipoBeneficiario">
    <option value="0">Selecione</option>
    <option value="1">Conjugue</option>
    <option value="2">Filho</option>
    <option value="3">Mãe/Pai</option>
    <option value="4">Compannheira(o)</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**Captura de Tela do formulário**

[image: Tela de alteração de dados]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Uma opção também, seria testar o valor para cada `option` e imprimir `selected` quando corresponder, exemplo:

```
<label>Tipo Beneficiario: </label> <span> <?php echo $TipoBeneficiario; ?></span>
<div class="">
  <select name="tipoBeneficiario">
    <option value="0" <?=($TipoBeneficiario == 'Selecione')?'selected':''?> >Selecione</option>
    <option value="1" <?=($TipoBeneficiario == 'Conjugue')?'selected':''?> >Conjugue</option>
    <option value="2" <?=($TipoBeneficiario == 'Filho')?'selected':''?> >Filho</option>
    <option value="3" <?=($TipoBeneficiario == 'Mãe/Pai')? 'selected':''?> >Mãe/Pai</option>
    <option value="4" <?=($TipoBeneficiario == 'Companheira(o)')?'selected':''?> >Compannheira(o)</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

No exemplo, a condição é testada utilizando [if ternário](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.php), onde

```
 <?=($TipoBeneficiario == 'Companheira(o)')? 'selected' : ''?>
```

é o mesmo que

```
<?php 
if($TipoBeneficiario == 'Companheira(o)'){
   echo 'selected';
}
?>
```

Se você não tem a opção de short tags habilitada no servidor ou prefere não utilizar, você pode fazer:

```
<label>Tipo Beneficiario: </label> <span> <?php echo $TipoBeneficiario; ?></span>
<div class="">
  <select name="tipoBeneficiario">
    <option value="0" <?php echo $TipoBeneficiario=='Selecione'?'selected':'';?> >Selecione</option>
    <option value="1" <?php echo $TipoBeneficiario=='Conjugue'?'selected':'';?> >Conjugue</option>
    <option value="2" <?php echo $TipoBeneficiario=='Filho'?'selected':'';?> >Filho</option>
    <option value="3" <?php echo $TipoBeneficiario=='Mãe/Pai'?'selected':'';?> >Mãe/Pai</option>
    <option value="4" <?php echo $TipoBeneficiario=='Companheira(o)'?'selected':'';?> >Companheira(o)</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Assumindo que o valor da caixa de selecção está contido na variavel `$TipoBeneficiario`, para que possas marcar determinada opção da caixa de selecção como `selected` deverás comparar cada uma das opções com o valor presente na variável.

Para o teu caso, parece que estás a guardar a legenda escolhida ao invés do valor da selecção. Assim sendo, podes fazer a comparação da seguinte forma:

### Verificar qual está seleccionado

```php
// inicializar variáveis a vazio
$check0 = $check1 = $check2 = $check3 = $check4 = "";

/* verificar qual o valor contido na variável $TipoBeneficiario
 * e preencher a variável de marcação com o atributo "selected"
 */
switch ($TipoBeneficiario) {
  case "Selecione": {
    $check0 = "selected";
    break;
  }
  case "Conjugue": {
    $check1 = "selected";
    break;
  }
  case "Filho": {
    $check2 = "selected";
    break;
  }
  case "Mãe/Pai": {
    $check3 = "selected";
    break;
  }
  case "Compannheira(o)": {
    $check4 = "selected";
    break;
  }
}
```

### Fazer output

```php
echo '
<label>Tipo Beneficiario:  </label>  <span> '.$TipoBeneficiario.'</span>
<div class="">
  <select name="tipoBeneficiario">
    <option value="0" '.$check0.'>Selecione</option>
    <option value="1" '.$check1.'>Conjugue</option>
    <option value="2" '.$check2.'>Filho</option>
    <option value="3" '.$check3.'>Mãe/Pai</option>
    <option value="4" '.$check4.'>Compannheira(o)</option>
  </select>
</div>';
```